# Organizing Java Code with inner classes

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, namespaces

this is a question of good practices and organization.

In JavaScript, I'm used to organizing even small parts of code into `objects` like this:

```
var init{
  menu: function(){...},
  navBar: function(){...},
  connection: function(){...},
};

// And then call it like:
init.menu();
init.navBar();
[...]
```

I want to be able to do that, but haven't found a good way to doit. Grouping it inside static classes make it difficult to access the `Activity`. Instantiating a class, just for that, seems to much for me.

Here is what I came up with, but I don't actually like it because I have to assign the `context`, and instantiate it as a helper class:

```
SwitchToHelper switchTo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        [...]

        // Instantiate fragment helper
        switchTo = new SwitchToHelper(this);
        switchTo.Feed();
}

class SwitchToHelper{
        FragmentActivity context;
        // This is a default viewId to be used
        int defaultViewId;

        SwitchToHelper(FragmentActivity context) {
            this.context = context;
            defaultViewId = R.id.fragment;
        }

        void Feed(){
            // Creates and switches fragment
            Fragment feedFragment = FeedFragment.newInstance();
            makeTransaction(feedFragment).commit();
        }
}
```

Do you know good practices for that?

Thanks

Comment: I think I don't really understand your question. In Java it is the normal way to store everything (except primitives) in objects so it is basically the same idea. Ok there are also a lot of differents like class concept in Java versus the prototype and adding values on the fly into object in javascript. But the main idea is the same...

Comment: Java != JavaScript.  I wouldn't try to write Java that way.  Those would just be methods in your class.  I see no need for inner classes here.

Comment: @duffymo I want to organize my code. I can do it with C++, JavaScript, ObjectiveC and I want to find out a (cool) way of doing it in Java

Comment: @Ennosigaeon I have added my current structured code in Java... Want to do the same, without the use of instantiation. It's just a matter of namespaces...

Comment: But you have to call the constructor/instantiate the object, that is the normal way in Java. Javascript does exactly the same when you create a object with `new`. Otherwise the default prototype is called.

Comment: If `SwitchToHelper` is not a `static class` then it has access to its parent's class' attributes and methods. You don't need the `context`.

Comment: @agbinfo 1/2 of the problem is gone... I don't want to instantiate the helper. It could be static, but then I wouldn't have access to the parent attributes... Any ideas?

Comment: To get access to the parent's attributes, you need a reference to it. What's wrong with `SwitchToHelper.Feed(this)`?

Comment: @agbinfo there will be lot's of other methods inside it... Rather not need to pass the activity every time. Is there a way out?

Comment: You claim to write C++ and Objective C, yet you have no idea how to organize code in Java?  Forget about (cool); write idiomatic code.

Comment: @duffymo If you can't help, don't bother...

Comment: What you'd need is an inner class with static methods. I don't think there's any technical reason it hasn't been done but as far as I know, it's not supported so you'll have to instantiate a class or pass a reference to the parent class explicitly.

Comment: You need to instantiate. Just because there's no explicit call to a constructor in the JavaScript example you give, doesn't mean there's no instantiation: `init` is still an object on equal footing with a String or DOM node.

Java just doesn't give you a way to implicitly construct objects like that. (Outside of a few special cases, like arrays.)

Comment: Something like a namespace (in C) would do the tricky... but I don't think there is any sort of thing like this in Java... Thanks @CCC

Comment: In Java they're called "packages".  If you can't code or read, don't bother.

Comment: @duffymo Ok intelligent guy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the closest solution I could come up with.

```
public class FragmentActivity {
  int v;

  class SwitchToHelperImpl {
    void Feed() {
      doSomethingFragmentActivity(FragmentActivity.this);
    }

    void doSomethingFragmentActivity(FragmentActivity frag) {
      System.out.println(frag.v);
    }
  }

  SwitchToHelperImpl SwitchToHelper = new SwitchToHelperImpl();

  public FragmentActivity(int v) {
    this.v = v;
  }

  public void onCreate() {
    SwitchToHelper.Feed();
  }
}
```